# Python Serialization with Append Support

Tags: python, numpy, serialization, computer-vision

I am working with a lot of objects that have some attributes as well as numpy arrays (images, masks, etc.). I want to dump them onto disk during program execution to save memory and want to append more data when it is available (during same program execution) without loading the dumped object into memory.

The problem is that appending data to serialized/pickled file cannot be done without first loading it into memory. How can I save/update (without loading the whole object) these objects during program execution? Any idea is welcome.

The below is pseudocode.

```
class StoredObject():
    def __init__(self, centroid, _image, _color, _bbox, _type, _mask):
        self.centroids = [centroid]
        self.bboxes = [_bbox]
        self.track_color = random_color()
        self.color = _color
        self.images = [_image]
        self.type = _type
        self.last_appear = time.time()
        self.masks = [_mask]

store = []

track_objects(obj, obj_image, obj_mask):
    if obj already belongs to store:
        find where it is stored earlier
            and add obj_image and obj_mask to its obj_image list
            and obj_mask list respectively
    else
        add obj(obj_image, obj_mask) in store
```

Comment: It is unclear as to what the problem is. The question needs to be complete. Pls [see](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @newkid I have stated the problem explicitly.

Comment: You are essentially trying to develop a database management software. You could look into [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org) or [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com). For images and multimedia objects the later seems to be a better choice. Else, you would have a growing database which will be very inefficient to scan and check if you have a bit-by-bit match for your objects.

Comment: @newkid Thanks. I was thinking the same thing. However, at the moment I have saved images and their mask in a predefined folder. Only their path is stored in the memory (objects attribute).

Comment: in the above form it wouldn’t be possible I’m afraid. Furthermore, I think it is not clear in your question as to how your container objects are created, managed and compared. An algorithm of your full program is needed in this case.